# Change position of several images using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't find the answer that helps me with my problem. I can change position of a div called .c-articleimage (which includes an image) to be placed after .c-article__lead with following code:

```
var articleimage = document.querySelector('.c-articleimage');
var newposition = document.querySelector('.c-article__lead');
newposition.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', articleimage);
```

But what if I have several .c-articleimage and .c-article__lead? I was thinking about I could use querySelectorAll? But I might need to loop it in some way?

```
var articleimage = document.querySelectorAll('.c-articleimage');
var newposition = document.querySelectorAll('.c-article__lead');
newposition.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', articleimage);
```

How can I tacle this?

Best,

Answer (score 0):

The function `insertAdjacentElement` works on nodes. However, both `articleimage` and `newposition` are nodelists. If you want to insert after the last `newposition` node, you need to select it:

```js
function moveai(){
  var articleimage = document.querySelectorAll('.c-articleimage');
var newposition = document.querySelectorAll('.c-article__lead');
  var lastnew = newposition.item(newposition.length - 1);
  articleimage.forEach(function(el){
    lastnew.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', el);
    lastnew = el;
  });
}
```

```css
.c-articleimage{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class='c-articleimage'>One</div>
<div class='c-articleimage'>Two</div>
<div class='c-article__lead'>Three</div>
<div class='c-article__lead'>Four</div>

<button onclick='moveai()'>Move</button>
```

If you press the button, elements `One` and `Two` move below `Three` and `Four`.